# Strong parameter error when creating a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

This is what I am trying to do here. I call a function test from user controller. and inside the test function I initialize a new article object like this `article = new Article`. But this gives me error

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#create
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

I have following code

users_controller

```
def create
 User.test
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, articles_attributes:[:content)
end
```

User model

```
class User

def self.test
  article = new Article
  article.attributes = {"content"=>"this is some sample content"}
  article.save
end

end
```

I know this question has been asked and answered lots of time but I could not find anything that matches with my problem or a solution for this. So please tell me how to save the article object inside user model call.

Comment: How is `article = new Article` even working? Oh I see. its calling `Class#new` and then passing in Class definition of itself... so it compiles. but its still not doing what you think it is. Try `article = Article.new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is `article = new Article` even working? Oh I see. its calling `Class#new` and then passing in Class definition of itself... so it compiles. but its still not doing what you think it is. Try `article = Article.new`

Also, your assignment inside the User model has no bearing on the controller `user_params` method which sanitizes your parameters